# How to remove expand on label click on TextNode YUI Treeview?

Tags: javascript, yui, yahoo

I want to expand the Node only on click on Icon not on the label.

With yahoo ui 2.7 :

```
selfCategoryTree.tree.subscribe("labelClick", function(node) {
    alert(node.data.customData.id + " label was clicked");
});
```

So I catch the `labelClick`, I show an alert, but the Node is expanded.

EDIT:

I do this :

```
tree.subscribe("clickEvent", TreeOnClickEvent, this, true);
var TreeOnClickEvent = function(event, args){
    return false;
}
```

It's working fine but I don't get the node in `TreeOnClickEvent`.
In documentation, `args` is the node (if I understand) but I don't get the label on `args`.

Any idea ?